# Json at position error

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js

I am using passport.js for my backend (node.js) app to signin up the user. I am getting always following error:

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>     at Object.parse ()
>       at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json
>   (http.es5.js:797)
>       at MapSubscriber.project (signup.component.ts:31)

After refresh the site I am signed-up. What is wrong with my code?

Here is my angular function:

```
signUp() {

    this.userNotExist = "";
    this.userExist="";

        this.http.post('/signup',this.signform.value).map((res: any) => res.json())
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
            console.log('TTTTTTTTT')
                console.log(res) 
                console.log('TTTTTTTTT')
                if(res=='EXIST'){
                    this.userNotExist = "";
                    this.userExist = 'The email already exists';
                }else {
                    this.userExist = "";
                    this.userNotExist = 'Congrats! You are now signed up';
                    window.location.reload();


                }
            }

        ),(error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            }

}
```

My Node.js app:

```
 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            nameMainField : 'nameMain',
            firstNameField: 'firstName',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {

            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }).lean().exec( function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error

                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email already exists.'));
                } else {

                    var newUserS           = new User();

                    // set the user's local credentials
                    newUserS.local.email    = email;
                    newUserS.local.password = newUserS.generateHash(password); // use the generateHash function in our user model
                    newUserS.local.nameMain = req.body.firstName + ' ' + req.body.nameMain;
                    newUserS.local.firstName = req.body.firstName;
                    newUserS.role=0;
                    newUserS.profileImage='/assets/fonts/male.png';

                    // save the user
                    newUserS.save(function(err, u) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;

                        return done(null, newUserS);
                    });
                }
            });

        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `xml` response instead of `JSON` response. I am pretty sure it is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay//DTD WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN" 
  "http://dtd.WorldPay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="ExampleCode1"> <!--The merchantCode you supplied originally-->
  <reply>
    <orderStatus orderCode="ExampleOrder1"> <!--Not present for parse or security violation errors-->
      <error code="2">
        <![CDATA[Invalid address: Postal code is missing or empty.]]>
      </error>
    </orderStatus>
  </reply>
</paymentService>
```

The exception comes from the first char at the xml response.

Comment: I dont think so because I am using MongoDB Mongoose to for retrieving the data.

Comment: Check out your network. You get the error exactly at map((res: any) => res.json()) while trying to map the response to JSON. You are getting xml response I am sure.